# Error in next module federation: `TypeError: g.useSyncExternalStore is not a function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webpack-module-federation

I'm getting below error after deploying next app with module federation:

```
TypeError: g.useSyncExternalStore is not a function
```

Same app working as standlone application means when run yarn dev/yarn start, but failing in module federation.

these are the version:

```
"@module-federation/nextjs-mf": "7.0.8",
 "next": "14.0.4",
 "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
 "webpack": "^5.90.1",
 "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.22.2",
```

Workaround:
we recently upgraded react-query(3.x.x) to @tanstack/react-query(^5.22.2).

In new tanstack/react-query they are using useSyncExternalStore hook, which is already available in react 18.

but somehow it's not working in module federation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is hook `useSyncExternalStore` is not supported in module federation, but the same hook is used in `"@tanstack/react-query": "^5.22.2"` which is causing the issue.

So downgrading tanstack/react-query to 4.x.x worked, specifically latest version in release 4 is `4.24.10`.